# Search Excel Number No Results

Tags: search, excel

Using SharePoint search in 2016 continuous crawl, search will not find any results for number fields in an Excel file.

This worked in 2010. Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: Even I have experienced some times, so better go with text/string , rather than INT.